# How to configure multiple directories on Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, httpd

I'm working on ubuntu with apache2.

**Requirements**

1. The root directory should be served from a specific folder. When someone accesses http://mysite.com/foo1 he should reach `/var/www/tld/foo1`
2. Other directories as sub-sites: When someone accesses http://mysite.com/subsite/foo2 he should reach `/var/www/subsite/foo2`
3. I would like to be able to configure specific shortcuts for some actions. E.g. by adding a custom rule, I would like http://mysite.com/foo3 to reach http://mysite.com/subsite/foo3 (unlike #1, this is not global, but just by adding specific routes).

What's the best way to achieve this? Should I have a different file under `apache/site-enabled` per "subsite"? Or should I use `<Directory>`? How do I configure `mod_rewrite` to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A virtualhost has only one documentroot; apache has no concept of "subsites".

[Vhosting documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html)

You can make exceptions to this by adding an Alias that points to a filesystem location *outside* the documentroot, but take care in what order you define these: the first match wins, so you should order them from most specific to least specific.

[Alias documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias)

The last question is more a case of bad site layout, but you could issue a Redirect for it:

```
Redirect /foo3/ /subsite/foo3/
```

There is no module named mod_routing in apache.

Comment: Removed mod_routing, evaluating the rest of you answer. I'll try out Aliases.

Comment: On ubuntu, the solution was editing `mods-enabled/alias.conf` and adding `Alias /foo2 "/var/www/foo2"`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If all URLs are hosted under the same domain/IP address, you can use mod_rewrite to rewrite the URLs according to the rules you specify.

Comment: See above (Replaced `mod_routing` with `mod_routing/mod_rewrite`): `How do I configure mod_routing/mod_rewrite to achieve this`? You can tell me to RTFM if you want.

Comment: There are many documentation on using mod_rewrite. You can start using it and if you need help you can ask another question.